# ImageButton setOnClick listener is Not Working in TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, imagebutton

I have just an ImageButton and TextView. I just want to write some text in TextView when i clicked the ImageButton. Here is my code.

```
final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                txt.setText("abc");
            }
        });
```

In this case, this code is working as i want.
But when i want to use it within "tabhost" , it is not working.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: and where are you placing this in tabhost?

Comment: firstly, i put tabhost from palette , then i put imagebutton and textview to tab1

Comment: Have you used (android:clickable="true" ) for imageView/imageButton in xml or (btn.setClickable=true) in java

Comment: I used android:clickable="true" in xml and btn.setClickable=true in java

Answer (score 0):

Try using ImageButton.OnClickListener instead of View.OnClickListener